# Cordova WP8 app restarts(starts with home page) after invoking camera or photo album

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins

I am developing an hybrid app using cordova 6.x.x

Goal is to support windows Phone 8.1, but I am facing difficulties in getting the captured image from camera or Album. Every time app navigates back to login.html after selecting the image.

I am using the below code for invoking camera. Same code works fine for iOS and Android platforms. But in WP8 call back will not be called as the page redirects to the login screen.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture (onSuccess, onFail,
                             { quality: 50,
                             destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                             allowEdit: 1,
                             saveToPhotoAlbum : true,
                             width: compRatio,
                             height: compRatio
                             });

function onSuccess (imageData) {
}

function onFail(imageData) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using visual studio for app development then it might happen. I prefer you to build your app using command line. Just create a new project, add platform, add plugins, place your www folder in the project. And build the project. Do all this by CLI.

Comment: Thanks for your quick turn around. 
I am doing exactly what you said above but still no luck.

Comment: I have used "windows" command to create and build so its universal.

Comment: pls use wp8 or 8.1 but not universal. The functionality of universal is quite different from wp. Because it is designed to support PC also.  start it from scratch. cordova platform add wp8. cordova run wp8......

Comment: i tried this solution, for some reason UI is not proper compared to the exixting universal app (may be coz of webview) also not able to debug getting message "break point will not hit. Symbols not loaded"

Comment: There is no bug in your UI. There should be bug in javascript. First make sample app. And then add your code step by step. I also had the same issue. I had fixed it using wp8.

Comment: Had created a sample project with just index.js but unable to hit break point on document ready function.

Comment: It will work. First check your code in browser. Check it for any console error. Fix it first. And if that js work in browser it will definitely work on your device.

Comment: Shahbaz, I really appreciate for your help. But as i said its the same issue, works fine on browser.

Comment: Sandy, I am not assuming this. It works in case of mine. I had the same issue. Universal windows platform is not suitable for hybrid application development. You can trace the bug by running it using visual studio. Change your build platform to wp8. I have made many hybrid applications. Is it possible that some js works on browser but not in device ???

Comment: I agree that building wp8 may solve navigation issue, but unable to proceed further coz of "Symbols not loaded " issue.  Sure I will let you know if I find anything